# Create a new folder by using OS notation in Java

Tags: java, operating-system, directory

Given the `Path` object that points to a folder, e.g. `c:\pluto`, how can I generate a new empty folder in Java without taking care of the folder name?

E.g. when I call a method, say `X()`, it should create a new folder to path `c:\pluto\new folder`. If I press again it must create `c:\pluto\new folder (1)`, pressing again I must obtain `c:\pluto\new folder (2)`, etc.

Why I need interaction with OS? Because the name of a standard new folder changes with regard to the OS and the OS language.

Honestly I have no experience with interaction of Java applications toward OSs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.valueOf(System.nanoTime)` to generate folder name. It will generate unique folder name for every call. Then concat this folder name with base path and voila, you have a unique folder name.

Use `File.separator` to separate base path and generated folder name.

**UPDATE:**

If folder names will be shown/selected via user interface, then aforecited approach could not be suitable. Then use a mask and number. For mask, let it be `new folder (%n%)`. Where `%n%` will be generated number or date string.

To check folder presence in your code use the following method:

```
private static boolean doesFolderExist(String folderPath) {
    final File folderHandler = new File(folderPath);
    return folderHandler.isDirectory();
}
```

But from my point of view I would ask user for a name for a new folder, instead of generating it automatically. And only if user do not want to input name for new folder, only in this case I would generate it automatically. Folder presence check will run in any case.

Comment: This is an answer based on logic, but it is not the answer... Moreover, let me say that `System.nanoTime` this will not guarantee that a unique folder name is generated: one has to verify if the generated folder name matches any existing Path, and eventually generate another folder name: it is a rare case, less frequent than meteorites on the Earth, but possible!

Comment: I supposed you generate these names in one-thread environment. Ok, then consider [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class instead of `nanoTime` call. In the most cases this approach is acceptable without checking the presence of this folder in the system. If no, please provide more details about your application. Why do you need `real`, not `pseudo-real` unique names.

Comment: Because the new folder name has to be shown in a JFileChooser, and I want to let it compliant with the OS language and style!